# How to format a USB stick with gparted under Linux so it shows up on a Mac?

Tags: linux, mac, usb, gparted

I have a USB stick I want to use with a Mac. However, when plugging it in to a Mac it does not even show up in the Mac on "DiskUtility". So I cannot use the Mac to format the USB drive.

How can I format this USB stick using `gparted` on a Linux device so it can be used/recognized with a Mac?

HINT: The USB drive is perfectly fine, the connections are perfectly fine, the USB ports work fine on the Mac side. There is NO problem with a technical connection anywhere!

Comment: In Disk Utility do you have it set to show devices or just volumes? [Cmd/2 will show devices]

Comment: I tried both, the device does not show up

Comment: Reboot, try again. Try a different port/reader. If the hardware isn't recognised, no partition on it will be recognised either.

Comment: If it does not show up in Disk Utility at all, the problem is not with partitioning. Check with _System Information.app_: Does macOS see the USB device at all?

Comment: Where can I see the useful information in the System Information.app? I am using a hard ware extension to connect to USB-A USB sticks, The mac only has USB-C

Comment: Also, all other hardware I connect to the port is recognized. External wired mouse, other external USB sticks and hard drives. No problem at all

Comment: You can see all USB devices under _Hardware_ → _USB_. The information does not refresh automatically. Press Cmd+R to manually refresh it.

Comment: I only see the "Anker USB-C Hub device"

Comment: So, unfortunately, it looks like there is a problem with the connection after all. You should now check other USB-C hubs/adapters and also other USB-C hosts (PC, laptop, phone, …).

Answer (score 3):

This is a summary of the article
[Formatting USB flash drive for macOS on Ubuntu](https://artiya4u.medium.com/formatting-usb-flash-drive-for-macos-on-ubuntu-f445c6b052bb).

- Open GParted and select your flash drive
- Right-click and select "Unmount" on all its partitions
- Select menu *Device > Create Partition Table…*
- Choose "gpt" and click "Apply"
- Right-click on the unallocated space, select "New" and "fat32"
- Click "Add"
- Click the checkbox on top to apply all operations and wait
- Remove and re-insert to access the new drive.

For more information with screenshots, see the linked article.

Comment: This answers the question as asked, but the question was really an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) - so it won't actually help the OP to achieve their true aim; to mount the drive on the Mac.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but this procedure does not seem to work. The MacOS still does not recognise the drive in any way.

Comment: If it doesn't show at all on the Mac and cannot even be formatted, then it's somehow not compatible with your Mac. You might try another stick that the Mac likes better.